# View palette for GIF image?

Tags: gif

How can I view the palette of a GIF image?

I'm using gd in php to add some text to a template image. I'm specifying black as the color for the text, but it shows up as olive. I suspect that true black isn't in the palette of the GIF, so I'm looking to view the palette to validate my hypothesis.

Comment: Are you trying to read the palette in code or find an application which will allow you to directly view the colours in the palette? Old apps like Corel PhotoPaint used to do this, I think DPaint did too. I just looked and PaintShopPro shows the palette and you can load it and change the order to palette number / hue / luminance  to get a better idea what is in there.

Answer (score 0):

the gd function `imagecolorclosest` in php at least gave me a workaround.